# What are the default locations that OSQL and SQLCMD search to connect to a server when -S option is not specified?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd, osql

I am trying to identify how `osql` and `sqlcmd` resolve server name and user to connect to that server when we do not specify server using `-S` option and use `-E` option. Below is the output for various queries I ran.

1. List all available servers on the network
   `osql -L`  -- Returns all the servers on the network except the one that it connects to by default
   `sqlcmd -L` -- Returns the same list as above
2. Connect to the default server without using `-S` option
   `osql -E -d dbname -Q "select current_user"` -- does not return the current user. Instead returns a user configured in the SQL server which I can see is present in windows registry but not sure how any why `osql` picks it.
   `sqlcmd -E -d dbname -Q "select current_user"` -- gives and error `Named pipes provider: Could not open connection to SQL Server`
3. Connect using server name and `-S` option
   `osql -E -S servername -d dbname -Q "select current_user"` -- same output as in point 2 above
   `sqlcmd -E -S servername -d dbname -Q "select current_user"` -- gives the login id used to login to the system from where I am executing this query\
4. Execute command remotely
   `osql -E -d dbname -Q "select current_user"` -- gives the same output as point 2
   `sqlcmd -E -s servername -d dbname -Q "select current_user"` -- throws an error `Login failed for computername` where computername is the actual windows computer name

I have been at it for days now trying to find how is `osql` working. I need to figure this out to move to `sqlcmd`.

**Edit 1:** I can confirm that there is no environment variable OSQLSERVER

Comment: `ChatGPT could not help either.` did you expect otherwise? Have you actually checked the [-S parameter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#-s-protocolserverinstance_nameport)?

Comment: Yup. Since I used it to solve few issues with some legacy code. Yes, I did check the documentation and it is how it works for sqlcmd. I am all good with sqlcmd but not with osql.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? The answer is right there

Comment: Relevant [dcoumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/osql-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) for OSQL too. What about this and the other documentation didn't you understand about the `-S` parameter? We can then *try* to elaborate.

Comment: ChatGPT generates text based on your text. It needs *better* questions than the ones you'd ask another human, or post in a forum. Otherwise it just generates garbage that looks good enough if you don't know what the real answer should look like. If you're lucky, it will show you the actual documentation you'd have found yourself a lot sooner. If no, it will just generate nice looking fake stuff

Comment: Yeah. I know how to use ChatGPT.

Comment: And what does the [osql documentation say?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/osql-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) Did you read the `-S` section?

Comment: If you look at the different scenarios and the output that I got by using sqlcmd and osql you would understand that I referred the documentation first.

Comment: Maybe you should just specify the names and usernames explicitely instead of trying to reverse-engineer old Microsoft products with a lot of hair and magic gathered through the millenia

Comment: @siggemannen I would if I had a non-prod environment where I could test that. Since it is production only I just want to make sure I have done all I could before going down that path.

Comment: Being explicit certainly apepars to be the solution; if you want explicit expected behaviour then be explicit in that request.

Comment: If you always want to use the default instance on the same machine you can do `-S .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of effort, I found that our organization had built an executable and named it `osql`. That was the reason that a new installation was not working but the old one was.